# Store just the value of an object in a variable

Tags: powershell

I want to store just the *value* of a PowerShell object in a variable.

## Example

If we run:

```
$time = Get-Process System | select TotalProcessorTime
$time
```

**This is the current output:**

```
TotalProcessorTime
------------------
00:03:22.8281250
```

**This is the output I would like:**

```
00:03:22.8281250
```

## Discussion

How do we store just the value? If we run `$time | Get-Member`, we see that PowerShell has stored a `Selected.System.Diagnostics.Process` that has the following properties:

```
Name               MemberType   Definition
----               ----------   ----------
Equals             Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode        Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType            Method       type GetType()
ToString           Method       string ToString()
TotalProcessorTime NoteProperty System.TimeSpan TotalProcessorTime=00:03:22.8281250
```

I have tried getting the value by running both `$time.TotalProcessorTime` and `$time.ToString()` without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Object which produces that string "00:03:22.8281250":

`(Get-Process System).TotalProcessorTime`

The string itself:

`(Get-Process System).TotalProcessorTime.ToString()`

Comment: `$time = Get-Process System | select -ExpandProperty TotalProcessorTime` would also have worked.