# Invoke-Command return information to be used in conditional statement Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arrayHold.length; $i++){
        $OSversion = invoke-command -computername $arrayHold[$i] -scriptblock {Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem} | select-object caption


    # create a nested for loop and throw the OSVERSION into it then nest the $i for loop.           
    #if ($OSversion -match "7"){
        $invcmd = invoke-command -computerName  -scriptblock {Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1} | select-object PSComputerName, SMB1 | format-table -autosize 


            #$printInfo = $OSversion + $invcmd
        $array += $invcmd   


    #}  
}
$array | out-file $save\"$file"
```

Returns:

```
PSComputerName SMB1
-------------- ----
XXXXXXXX          0
```

I want to do an IF statement that just looks to see if SMBv1 is equal to 1. How do I suppress the header information and write the statement?

Comment: Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets as intermediate step in data processing.

Comment: I use it to make it readable. Otherwise it is stretched. Does it muck with things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store just the value of an object in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517323/store-just-the-value-of-an-object-in-a-variable)

Comment: Yes it mucks with things; it changes an object with properties you can work with easily, into a string representation of a table with less information in it, some possibly cut short, which you can't easily work with. You want to read up on `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arrayHold = @("TEST_COMPUTER")
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $arrayHold.length; $i++){
    $OSversion = invoke-command -computername $arrayHold[$i] -scriptblock {Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem} | select-object caption
    $invcmd = invoke-command -computerName $arrayHold[$i]  -scriptblock {Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\" | select-object PSComputerName, SMB1} 
    $invcmd

    if($invcmd.SMB1 -eq 1){
        "1"
    }elseif(!$invcmd.smb1){
        "2"
    }else{
        "3"
    }
}
```

Comment: tat gross "SMBv1 -eq 1" :D

Comment: I will give this a shot